# constructor and destructor calls involved in object creation

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I am using the following code snippet to compare two methods for creating an object in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() : x(0) { cout << "In Foo constructor." << endl; }
        ~Foo() { cout << "In Foo destructor." << endl; }
        Foo(const Foo&) { cout << "In Foo copy constructor." << endl; }

        // Assignment operator.
        Foo& operator=(const Foo&) {
            cout << "In assignment operator." << endl;
            return *this;
        }

    private:
        int x;
};

int main() {

    cout << "Constructing Foo 1" << endl;
    Foo Foo_1;
    cout << "Constructing Foo 2" << endl;
    Foo Foo_2 = Foo();

    return 0;
}
```

The output from this code snippet is:

```
  Constructing Foo 1
  In Foo constructor.
  Constructing Foo 2
  In Foo constructor.
  In Foo destructor.
  In Foo destructor.
```

I am using **Visual C++ 2010** (compiler version 16.x) and I am compiling the snippet using `cl /EHsc /W4 test.cpp`. In the construction of `Foo_2`, I was expecting to see an extra call to the constructor and destructor in order to create a temporary object and a call to the assignment operator in order to assign the temporary object to `Foo_2`. Can someone explain to me why this is not the case. Apologies if I am missing something very obvious here.

Answer (score 4):

There are two forms of initialization available for `Foo`:

```
Foo f1;
Foo f2 = Foo();
```

The first constructs `f` directly, using the default constructor. The second constructs a temporary of type `Foo`, using the default constructor, and copies that temporary into `f2`. The latter is what you describe as what you expected. And you're right, except for one additional rule: if that form of initialization is valid (which it is here; make the copy constructor private and see what happens), the compiler is allowed to "elide" the copy construction and construct `f2` directly, just as in the first version. That's what you're seeing. The compiler isn't required to elide the copy constructor, but every one I've used recently does.

Comment: Hi Pete, Thanks a lot for the feedback. This explains it for me.

Comment: Hi Pete, I tried your test of making the copy constructor private and the code does not compile. It states that it cannot access private member Foo::Foo. My question now is that if it is copy constructing then why do I not see "In Foo copy constructor." in the output.

Comment: Hi, Apologies, I think that I see from the link in Sapien2's post why I am not seeing it. The compiler optimizes it away. Quote from the link: "The compiler is actually allowed (but not required) to optimize away the copy construction in this kind of situation. If it does optimize it, the copy ctor must still be accessible." You say this above also.

Comment: @Francis - right. The compiler can skip the copy constructor, but only if it's available. So making it private makes copy construction invalid, and eliding the copy constructor then is also invalid.

Answer (score 1):

`Foo Foo_2 = Foo();` is similar to `Foo Foo_2(Foo());`. Compiler is smart enough to do this, no assignment operator is being called. BTW, you have a bug in the assignment operator - you return reference to your object instead of copying it.

Comment: No, it's not syntax sugar. Make `Foo`'s copy constructor private and try it again.

Comment: @Pete Becker - my bad, fixed the reply

Comment: `Foo Foo_2(Foo());` does not explain why there are only two constructors in his sample rather than three.

Answer (score 1):

The very first  "Guru of the Week" problem is just about your question http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/001.htm
Especially a note of compiler optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is helpful also. I should have done more googling before asking!!